# Book's mistake on existence of solution of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, lipschitz-functions

Is there a mistake in the book :
https://dropmefiles.com/UWLei

**Hypothesis (H) (cf page 35)**

Consider $g$ continuous on $(a,b)\times \mathbb{R}^n$, $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$, and
$x\mapsto f(t,x)$ continuously differentiable for all $t\in (a,b)$ .

At the top of page 36, the authors say that $f$ satisfies hypothesis (C) of page 14, which in particular means that $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$.

Comment: Can you write out the sections/equations you are referring to or mention which book you are referring to? Namely, links can brake leaving your question incomplete afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If the hypothesis is that the function is continuously differentiable, the derivatives will be continuous on a compact domain and therefore bounded.  This implies that there is a uniform Lipschitz constant.  If in your example the Lipschitz constant "depends on $t$", this would mean that the example does not satisfy their hypothesis.

Comment: @Smilia, sorry, I missed that.  Reading it quickly, I thought they are talking about a continuously differentiable function of two variables.  So you may have accepted my answer too quickly.  I think there is still time to un-accept.

Comment: Indeed I just reflected on that.

They only say $C^1$ with respect to $x$ so it doesn't imply that $t\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x)$ is continuous for any $x$ right ? so my example satisfies their assumptions and shows a mistake in their statement ?